# How do I give my drawers more detail?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hello I am trying to make a desk. I have used two Alex drawers from ikea as leg units but there's no way of differentiating its walls with the units themselves. How can I make this possible? I've tried using the solidify mod but it didn't work out well.

Drawer:
[image]

[.Blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vv7UcDIF1B30QrG2PPhEUNGrHot8PxdD)

Please tell me if you need me to elaborate.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drawers are separate objects in reality, there are no reason not to make separate meshes in 3D, especially if you want to make some close shots of the desk. Also, you need to keep quads as much as possible, meaning surfaces that have 4 vertices and not 5 or more. For example let's take one of your drawer:

- Make it a separate mesh (I've deleted the rest of the object to make it simpler).
- It looks like you have a lot of overlaying vertices, so to clean all this press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. On the top of the 3D view the amount of deleted vertices will be displayed.
- Delete useless vertices with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*.
- Also delete vertices that are not part of any face with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Vertices*.
- To make quads, use the knife, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally.
- Once you have only quads, extrude the whole surface with <kbd>E</kbd>.
- If the normals are flipped, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.
- Now you have the facade of one drawer.
- You can add depth with some edge loops <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and extrudes <kbd>E</kbd>.
- Etc...

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand how you did it. Whenever I try to subdivide it I only get vertices and no new faces and if I join those vertices with F I still don't get new faces. J doesn't work for me, it only says "Invalid selection order". Are there perhaps any videos for something similar to this? I really need clarification and I don't think I would understand if only images were used, if so I'd need like 50+.

Comment: Nevermind, I made faces in the traditional way by selecting vertices and pressing F. I then removed the original face and then followed your guide. Thank you!

Comment: actually I've edited my answer, use the knife tool, it will be much easier

Comment: second edit: I've added an explanation about the difference between join and fill.